# Next-Auth middleware too many redirects when I use custome sign in page

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

I've created nextJS 13.2 with next-auth and a custom sign-in page
it works fine. But the error is after adding middleware.js in the project root directory.
Too many redirects to default sign-in page and custom sign in page

```
    import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
const users = [
    { id: '1', username: 'abi', password: 'Abcd@1234' },
    { id: '2', username: 'abr', password: 'Abcd@1234' }
];
const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'ID',
            credentials: {
                username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text', placeholder: 'ID' },
                password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' }
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                if (!credentials || !credentials.username || !credentials.password) {
                    return null;
                }
                const user = users.find((item) => item.username === credentials.username);
                if (user?.password === credentials.password) {
                    return user;
                }
                return null;
            }
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
            if (account) {
                console.log('token', token);
                token.accessToken = account.access_token;
                token.id = profile.id;
            }
            return token;
        },
        session({ session, token }) {
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
            session.id = token.sub;
            return session;
        },
        redirect({ baseUrl }) {
            return baseUrl;
        }
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt'
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/auth/login',
        error: '/auth/error'
    }
};
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

but when I use  the middleware.js to protect routes, too many redirects to the default sign-in page and the customer sign in page

```
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware';
```

please anyone help me!